# VueJS - "this" is undefined in common function

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to extract a function for use across multiple components, but "this" is undefined and I'm unsure of the best practice approach of how to attach the scope so my function knows what "this" is.  Can I just pass it as an argument?

Component:-

```
import goToEvent from "@/common";

export default {
  name: "update",
  methods: {
    goToEvent
```

common function:-

```
let goToEvent = (event, upcoming=false) => {
    this.$store.dispatch({
        type: 'setEventsDay',
        day: event.start_date
    })
}
export default goToEvent
```

When I call goToEvent in my component, I get TypeError: Cannot read property '$store' of undefined.  How do I avoid this?

Comment: `this` is resolved lexically for arrow functions. You probably need a normal one instead. Or some reference to `$store`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation I recommend to define `eventable` as a mixin :

```
const eventable= {
  methods: {
   goToEvent(event, upcoming=false) {
     this.$store.dispatch({
        type: 'setEventsDay',
        day: event.start_date
      })
   }
  }
}

export default eventable;
```

in your vue file :

```
import eventable from "@/eventable";

export default {
  name: "update",
  mixins:[eventable],
....
```

**second solution** :

export an object with the function as nested method then import it and spread it inside the `methods` option :

```
export default {
    goToEvent(event, upcoming=false){
       this.$store.dispatch({
         type: 'setEventsDay',
        day: event.start_date
    })
   }
 }
```

then :

```
import goToEvent from "@/common";

export default {
  name: "update",
  methods: {
    ...goToEvent,
    otherMethod(){},
 }

//....
}
```

Comment: So what happens when this file has 50 functions in it?  Is there a way to import only one method for a mixin?

Comment: You could create multiple mixins in many files as you want, for example you could create one file named `eventable.js` that contains the mixin above

Comment: mixin groups one feature and it enforces the code reusability

Answer (score 0):

You're tagged with Typescript, so you need to tell TS that `this` actually has a value (note, I do not know VueJS, am using the generic `Event` types here, there is likely a more valid and correct type!)

First option, manually tell it what there is -

`let goToEvent = (this:Event, event, upcoming=false) => {`

Other option - tell it what type it is -

`let goToEvent: EventHandler = (event, upcoming=false) => {`

Of the two I personally prefer the second style for readability.

Comment: The arrow function will always override the value of `this` - so while this answer is not correct, it may be of use - please don't upvote!!

Answer (score -1):

There are numerous ways to achieve this, here are some that I like to use in my projects:

### Method 1: Mixins

Mixins are great for sharing a bunch of methods across components and also easy to implement, although one big con is that you will not be able to import specific methods that you need. Within the mixin, `this` follows the rules as in components.

File: `@/mixins/eventable`

```
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  methods: {
    ...mapActions([])
    goToEvent (event, upcoming = false) {
      store.dispatch({
        type: 'setEventsDay',
        day: event.start_date
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Usage in component:

```
import eventable from '@/mixins/eventable'

export default {
  name: 'ComponentName',
  mixins: [eventable],
  methods: {
    componentMethod () {
      this.goToEvent()
    }
  }
...
```

### Method 2: Static JavaScript files

In some cases, you might have a collection of helper functions kept in a file and want the ability to import as you need.

In your case, you seem to be using a store actions (assumed from the dispatch), hence I'll be including importing and using the store within the static JS file.

File: `@/static/js/eventable.js`

```
import store from 'path_to_store_file'

const goToEvent = () => {
  store.dispatch('actionName', payload)
}

export default {
  goToEvent
}
```

**Note:**
Although this is not entirely necessary, but only by declaring the imported function as a method within the component will it be bound to the component instance. This will allow you to access the function in the HTML portion.

Usage in component:

```
import { goToEvent } from '@/static/js/eventable.js'

export default {
  name: 'ComponentName',
  methods: {
    // Read note before this code block
    goToEvent,
    componentMethod () {
      // When declared as a method
      this.goToEvent()
      // When not declared, it can still be accessed in the js portion like this
      goToEvent()
    }
  }
...
```